# Updating help on PowerShell on Mac

Tags: macos, powershell, powershell-core

I'm new to PowerShell and I know on PowerShell on windows you need to run as administrator to update the help files, but how do you update help files on PowerShell on Mac?

Comment: su powershell update-help but it seems to fail for now= at least on "Ubuntu on windows"

Comment: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1889 https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1703

Comment: also https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8907

Answer (score 3):

At this time, it does not look like the Update-Help Cmdlet is supported for Mac or Linux. For the time being I would suggest going to the technet website for each help file.

You can get there from the Command Line with the -Online parameter:

```
Get-Help Write-Output -Online
```

or

```
Get-Help about_Functions -Online
```

These commands will take you directly to technet page you need. These pages will always be up to date.