# visual studio code power-shell update-help on mac

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I can't update update-help on powershell mac os
the error is :

> Update-Help : Failed to update Help for the module(s)
>   'Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive, Microsoft.PowerShell.Core,
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Host, Microsoft.PowerShell.Management,
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Security, Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility,
>   PackageManagement, PowerShellGet, PSReadLine' with UI culture(s)
>   {en-US} : Access to the path
>   '/usr/local/microsoft/powershell/6.0.1/en-US/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management.dll-Help.xml'
>   is denied.At line:1 char:1+ Update-Help
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Update-Help], Exception
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnknownErrorId,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.UpdateHelpCommand

Comment: Well, the error pretty much tells you what the problem is. The account you are running with does not have access to that path...

Comment: actually there is only one account and how to find this path or fix it

Comment: This is the path: '/usr/local/microsoft/powershell/6.0.1/en-US/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management.dll-Help.xml' as for how to fix it, that depends on how permissions are controlled in you environment.

Comment: i checked the path there is no Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management.dll-Help.xml file

Comment: Can you write to that path? Because if you can't then neither can the cmdlet to create the file.

Comment: /usr/local/microsoft/powershell/6.0.1/en-US/     but there is no                    microsoft.powershell.Commands.Managemnet.dll-help.xml file

Comment: Can you write to that path? Because if you can't then neither can the cmdlet ***to create the file***

Comment: yes I can write to the path but what the way to create the file

Comment: Try sudo'ing powershell then running Update-Help.

Comment: I should do sudo from terminal or visual studio code ?

Comment: Good lord, I don't know. I haven't worked on Macs in years. This is pretty simple troubleshooting. You could have probably already done it both ways in the time it took you to write that comment.

Comment: I already tried it but still its not working

Comment: What isn't working? Did you try it both ways? Did you get the same error both ways?

Answer (score 3):

Like you I don't spend much time on OSX, but I just did Update-Help on a default OSX install, latest version without use su and it updated just fine.

Try using the -force parameter.

Are you using a different language on your MAC. If you are try setting the culture to US English.

I have seen Update-Help fail even on Windows, if you are not running the VSCode / PowerShell session as admin, or if you are using a non-English OS SKU. So, then you'd do this...

```
Update-Help -UICulture en-US -Force -Verbose
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/update-help?view=powershell-5.1

Back in 2016, Update-Help failed for non-Windows clients. See this post.

> I'm new to PowerShell and I know on PowerShell on windows you need to
>   run as administrator to update the help files, but how do you update
>   help files on PowerShell on Mac?
>
> [Updating help on PowerShell on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427790/updating-help-on-powershell-on-mac)

But again, I read they got that fixed a while back and as noted, I just did this, and it works fine, even without / with  su.

As for some of the errors you are seeing, that is not uncommon to see certain modules not be able to update from time to time. I've seen this more than I care to over the years. I normally just suppress those errors these days.

```
Update-Help -UICulture en-US -Force -Verbose -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

This does not mean nothing updated as you'd see form the verbose output.

> Powershell command "update-help" fails
>
> When attempting to update the help information on a Windows 10 Pro
>   machine that is joined to a domain, I get this error message:
>
> https://partnersupport.microsoft.com/en-us/par_clientsol/forum/par_win/powershell-command-update-help-fails/d6e5b8b9-75fb-40e5-a90d-90f3dc797b14
>
> Update-Help fails to update 2 modules on Windows 10 Pro x64  #1766 
>   https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1766

Comment: thank you for the explanation but unfortunately  Update-Help -UICulture en-US -Force -Verbose doesn't do any difference still I can't update help and I can't get all the functions of get help like -examples

Comment: Is this problem just with my mac or its a common problem

Comment: Yep, something on your box. I rarely use the Mac I was issued, other than for software testing / validations, etc. It's a straight build, no special settings. So, unlike my daily drive Windows client that I have locked down. I am logged on the Mac with an account that has full administrative permissions as the default. Switch to an account that is full admin and then start PoSH via the terminal and give it a shot. Yep, I know VSC console is the same, but well, you  know. Lastly, uninstall PSCore and VSC and reinstall both, then try.